# There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 52,Token in error = ) ]

Tags: sql, razor, webmatrix

While trying to insert data to my SQl db i get the following error `System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException: There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 52,Token in error = ) ]`
my lines of code to enter the data are the following:

```
@{
var db= Database.Open("Games");
var sqlQ = "SELECT * FROM Games";
var data = db.Query(sqlQ);   
}
@{
if (IsPost) {
    var fileData = Request.Files[0];
    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(fileData.FileName);
    var fileSavePath = Server.MapPath("~/upload/" + fileName);
    fileData.SaveAs(fileSavePath);
    var GameName=Request["Name"];
    var Gamefile = fileName;
    var SQLINSERT = "INSERT INTO Games (Name, file_path) " + "VALUES (@0, @1,)";
    db.Execute(SQLINSERT, GameName, Gamefile);
    }
}
```

I am trying to upload a file to my server and add the filename to my database. The error is apparently with line 15.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trailing comma is my guess. change sql insert statement to this:

```
var SQLINSERT = "INSERT INTO Games (Name, file_path) " + "VALUES (@0, @1)";
```

Comment: I tried that and it fixed that error but now it is giving me another error

Comment: the error page now says: System.ArgumentNullException: Parameterized query expects a parameter value which was not supplied.
Parameter name: 0

Comment: @mhcodner: But that's an entirely different issue, isn't it. This answer solves the original issue in your post. Multiple questions are typically asked separately here (at least, when the issues are very different, like in your situation). Have a look at the existing questions too (there's a search bar at the top of the page), you may found a ready solution/answer among them.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in my case was in the middle of the sentence have the ' character

example (ERROR)

```
INSERT INTO Article (ARV_ARTICLE, ARV_NAME, ARV_BRAND_ID, ARV_GROUP) 
             VALUES ('56255249','**HANNA 70'S**','32','5')`
```

example (CORRECT)

```
INSERT INTO Article (ARV_ARTICLE, ARV_NAME, ARV_BRAND_ID, ARV_GROUP) 
             VALUES ('56255249','**HANNA 70S**','32','5')`
```

I resolve the problem with a subtract