# Migrations reporting error when trying to insert 0 or 1 to bit type column

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm trying to use insert into statement in migration class and once I try updating the database, I'm getting an error saying "There was an error parsing the query.

> [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 132,Token in error = 0 ]"

```
public override void Up()
{
   Sql("INSERT INTO Movies (UniqueID, Title, Actor, Genre, Deleted) VALUES ('1234567890123', 'Movie', 'John Smith', 'SciFi', 0 ");
}
```

"Deleted" is bit type, not null column, so I need to pass either 0 or 1, but it reports the error. I also tried passing "true"/"false" and '0'/'1', but it still doesn't work. What am I suppose to pass in order for this statement to work?

**edit:**
Now, I'm getting

> There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 89,Token in error = t ]

**edit2:**

I partially found the reason of error. It's because I have multiple Sql statements like this

```
public override void Up()
{
    Sql("INSERT INTO Movies (UniqueID, Title, Actor, Genre, Deleted) VALUES ('1234567890123', 'Movie', 'John Smith', 'SciFi', 0 ");
    Sql("INSERT INTO Movies (UniqueID, Title, Actor, Genre, Deleted) VALUES ('1234634534745', 'Movie2', 'Mike Johnson', 'SciFi', 0 ");
    Sql("INSERT INTO Movies (UniqueID, Title, Actor, Genre, Deleted) VALUES ('1234567890343', 'Movie3', 'George Smith', 'SciFi', 0 ");
}
```

but I have no idea why does this matter, when the lecturer I follow pass multiple lines like this when seeding the database and it works just fine for him.

**edit3**

I will just use it one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a closing parenthesis of `VALUES()`, change it to have closing parenthesis and it should work:

```
 VALUES ('1234567890123', 'Movie', 'John Smith', 'SciFi', 0)");
                                                           ^
                                                           |
                                                           | here
```

More better can be to put in variable the query and then use that variable down to avoid getting confused by parenthesis and you can also use [verbatim string literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090.aspx) to break it to multiple lines so that it can be more readable and it would also help to easily find any syntax mistakes:

```
public override void Up()
{
    var query = @"INSERT INTO Movies (UniqueID, Title, Actor, Genre, Deleted) 
                              VALUES ('1234567890123', 'Movie', 'John Smith', 'SciFi', 0)";
    Sql(query);
}
```

### SideNote:

Always double check your sql statements by testing somewhere that they execute and then put them in your code to safe yourself from this kind of trouble.

Comment: Thank you so much, that solved a problem with 0, but unfortunately, now I get almost the same error but stating "There was an error parsing the query. 

       [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 89,Token in error = t ]"

Comment: please add detailed error message in your question by editing it

Comment: Edited OP. That's it all what I'm getting. Now instead of 0 it shows t.

Comment: try wrapping your table and columns name is square brackets like: `[Movies]` and `[UniqueID],[Title],[Actor]` and so on

Comment: the following post might also be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9985746/there-was-an-error-parsing-the-query-token-line-number-1-token-line-offset

Comment: I partially found the reason of error. I have 4 of those Sql statements from OP in Up() method, but if I leave only 1 and delete other 3, it works just fine.

I have no idea why because lecturer I follow pass multiple Sql statements just fine without getting any error.

Comment: you possibly have special character in one of the values in that particular row values, can you edit your post with the actual statements you have there in code?

Comment: you might have this issue in your sql statement then :https://stackoverflow.com/a/27691811/1875256

Comment: Edited OP again. I doubt it's an issue in sql statement because I copy/pasted first line of Sql statement and just edited values. I just tried and one by one they work normally, meanwhile when I try migrating 2 Sql statements, that error appears.

Comment: Anyway thanks Ehsan! I will just use it one by one, since I can't bother to look further what causes the error.